# Python run an outside python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, sonos

Im trying to lock the volume of the sonos using SoCo in a webapp. I need to run a separate script to do this. So when the user presses the lock button it runs a loop constantly setting the volume to the value until the program gets called or toggled stopping it.
I need this done in a different script as if its in the main code i'm unable to get any user input to unlock it.

```
@app.route("/lock")
def lock():
    run(togglelock.py)
    return "ok"

#togglelock.py
toggle("F","T")
sound1 = (sonos.volume)
if toggle == "T":
sonos1.volume = sound1
else:
    break
```

Comment: `run(togglelock.py)` => `run("togglelock.py")` ?

Comment: run and toggle are not commands so the quotes don't really matter the whole line is out

Answer (score 0):

As long as the other python file is in the same directory, you can simply import it when you want to run it.

```
def lock():
import togglelock
return "ok"
#do more stuff....
```

Comment: Can I get the script to run separately outside the main script as its not possible to break out of the while loop ive created. As it enters the while loop spamming set volume to X and as now its only running that part of the code not checking the webapp if the button was pressed to turn it off.

Comment: It sounds like what you're wanting to do would require another instance of python. I don't think it's feasible to run two scripts in parallel like that. There maybe a way to add some kind of "event listener", but that may not be trivial.